# Key is shown as nan in dictionary python

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I am trying to convert a dataframe with 2 columns as dictionary with first column being key and second its value all in one dictionary.

Data sample:

```
id           summary
135791059    blha blah blah
135791051    blah something blah
```

And here is the code I have tried

```
map_of_values = pd.Series(f_dataframe.summary.values,index=f_dataframe.id).to_dict()

print(map_of_values)
```

The output is:

```
{'id': {'blah blah blah': nan, 'blah something blah}
```

I want it to be :

```
 {135791059:'blah blah blah blah',135791051:'blah something blah'}
```

What wrong am I doing? And also I want to iterate over each key value pair builing a string from it. Is it the right way?

Comment: `d=dict(df.values)` would do it if `id` is a column, also you can try`dict(zip(df.id,df.summary))` where `df` is the name of the dataframe

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your problem with the sample you provided; I get `{100: 'blha blah blah', 200: 'blah something blah'}`

Comment: Edit: I kept the values I am trying with for id. I still get the same result as before.

Comment: Thank you everyone for the answers. But in the code, I was doing some processing on the dataframe before converting it to a dictionary. That led to deletion of all the values in id field. Sorry , it was my bad!

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following code:

```
df.set_index('id').to_dict()['summary']
```

Comment: Same problem. The key is displayed as nan.

Answer (score 0):

Tried your solution as below.

working fine. Unable to reproduce the error. Maybe you want to check into your created data-frame.

```
f_dataframe= {'id':[135791059,135791051],
        'summary':["blha blah blah", "blah something blah"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(f_dataframe)

map_of_values = df.set_index('id').to_dict()['summary']
print(map_of_values)
```

Answer (score 0):

- [df.to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) method is used to convert a dataframe into a dictionary of series or list like data type depending on `orient` parameter.
- orient - String value, `('dict', 'list', 'series', 'split', 'records', 'index')` Defines which dtype to convert Columns(series into).

**Ex.**

```
import pandas as pd

my_dict = {'id':[135791059,135791051],'summary':["blha blah blah", "blah something blah"]}
df = pd.DataFrame(my_dict)
print(df)
records = df.to_dict('records')
data = {i['id'] :i['summary'] for i in records}
print(data)
```

**O/P:**

```
          id              summary
0  135791059       blha blah blah
1  135791051  blah something blah

{135791059: 'blha blah blah', 135791051: 'blah something blah'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem mostly happens if you already have used the values as a column. IF you have an existing column and want to attribute some 'key's to the values and make a new column, it will appear as `NaN`. You need to use the existing column as the 'key' and the desired new column as 'values' (by just switching the position of key and value in your dictionary).

For example: your pre-existing column is summary and your current dict is:

```
d = {135791059: 'blah blah blah', 135791051: 'blah something blah'}
```

However, You need to correct it like:

```
d = {'blah blah blah': 135791059: , 'blah something blah': 135791051}
```